# Expl3 and recent xparse on overleaf: No expl3 loader detected

Tags: installing, expl3, xparse

I'm currently writting a [library](https://github.com/leo-colisson/proof-at-the-end) that requires a recent xparse (to have the `+b` option for environments). Unfortunately, my computer does not have such recent xparse, so I downloaded the package [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/xparse?lang=en), ran

```
latex xparse.ins
```

and I copied the file into my project, together with my library. I put this file in the repository, so now one can simply do:

```
git clone https://github.com/leo-colisson/proof-at-the-end.git
pdflatex demo.tex && pdflatex demo.tex
```

to install and test the library, with a recent xparse. Great.

But there is an issue. My distro is pretty recent compared to overleaf (latex 2017 I think?) and unfortunately expl3 (used by xparse) is too old as well on overleaf (it does not provide `\c_novalue_tl` used by xparse). So my co-author cannot use the library on overleaf. Damn.

So I tried to download the library [expl3](https://ctan.org/pkg/expl3?lang=en), ran

```
latex l3.ins
```

And I copied the produced `expl3.sty` in my main project (so now I have `expl3.sty`, `xparse.sty`, `proof-at-the-end.sty`, and `demo.tex`). Boom! Now everything is broken:

- On my main computer I have an error:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty) (./xparse.sty
(./expl3.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex

! Package expl3 Error: Mismatched expl3 files detected.

See the expl3 package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.106 \next
```

- On overleaf I now have an error

```
 Package expl3 Error: No expl3 loader detected.

See the expl3 package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ... l.126 \next

You have attempted to use the expl3 code directly rather than using the correct loader. Loading of expl3 will abort.
```

I am really new to Latex 3, so I have no idea how to fix this issue, on both overleaf and on my local install. What is the proper way to "install" locally a recent expl3/xparse on a desktop and on overleaf, so that everybody can use my library by simply downloading a few files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to upload the entire `l3kernel`. The log says it used the local `expl3.sty` but used `expl3-code.tex` (the actual `expl3` code) from `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/`:

```
(./expl3.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex

! Package expl3 Error: Mismatched expl3 files detected.
```

You need to upload this file too to get it working. Better yet, upload the entire kernel (including driver files and other stuff that you might need):

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 phelype phelype 991026 Mai  7 13:25 expl3-code.tex
-rw-rw-r--  1 phelype phelype   2882 Mai  7 13:25 expl3-generic.tex
-rw-rw-r--  1 phelype phelype   3868 Mai  7 13:25 expl3.lua
-rw-rw-r--  1 phelype phelype   9894 Mai  7 13:25 expl3.sty
-rw-rw-r--  1 phelype phelype  20583 Mai  7 13:25 l3dvipdfmx.def
-rw-rw-r--  1 phelype phelype  37442 Mai  7 13:25 l3dvips.def
-rw-rw-r--  1 phelype phelype  15331 Mai  7 13:25 l3dvisvgm.def
-rw-rw-r--  1 phelype phelype  63076 Mai  7 13:25 l3names.def
-rw-rw-r--  1 phelype phelype  21611 Mai  7 13:25 l3pdfmode.def
-rw-rw-r--  1 phelype phelype  22242 Mai  7 13:25 l3xdvipdfmx.def
```

- `expl3-code.tex` is the actual `expl3` code. Without that nothing works;
- `expl3-generic.tex` is the generic loader, in case you are using other format other than LaTeX;
- `expl3.lua` are the Lua routines in case you are using `expl3` with LuaTeX;
- `expl3.sty` is the loader for LaTeX (counterpart of `expl3-generic.tex`);
- The remaining `.def` files are driver-specific definitions which are loaded depending on which engine you use.

Answer (score 5):

Phelype Oleinik has given an [excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489648) , but I'd like to point to a couple of another method.

We provide a [TDS-style zip file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel.tds.zip) which available from CTAN. This is 'pre-extracted' and explicitly contains a `tex/latex` directory with *all* of the run-time files in it. A copy of the content of that directory will always have a full set of matching files.

Comment: Nice :) I always go for the hard way :P

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Well I actually make those zip files ...

Comment: I always thought those were automagically generated by the system .-.

Comment: Uhm both answers looks great thanks, both of them should be accepted! Can I let these files in a subdirectory to avoid to pollute the main folder?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik In the sense `l3build`, which I wrote, makes them on my PC ...

Comment: @tobiasBora In a local machine I'd change `TEXINPUTS` directly. In Overleaf you can do [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_lot_of_.cls,_.sty,_.bst_files,_and_I_want_to_put_them_in_a_folder_to_keep_my_project_uncluttered._But_my_project_is_not_finding_them_to_compile_correctly).

Comment: That's perfect thanks!

Comment: This sounds very useful, but I have not managed to put the contents of that zipfile next to my main document in a way it gets picked up, with or without `TEXINPUTS` munging.

Comment: For example, unpacking this file (and `siunits.tds`) in the current directory and using `TEXINPUTS=./l3kernel.tds//:./siunitx.tds//: pdflatex siunit.tex` does not work – `exp3-code.tex` is not picked up from there.

Comment: Maybe that calls for a separate question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676615/installing-newer-expl3-via-the-tds-zip-file