# Installing newer expl3 via the tds.zip file

Tags: expl3, tds

In order to get a fixed version of another package, I need to upgrade `expl3`. As I am sharing this project, I’d prefer to put the new version next to the document.

I extracted the [`l3kernels.tds.zip`](https://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel.tds.zip) in a subdirecotry `l3kernels.tds/` of the directory with my document `test.text`, which is simply

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
Hello \LaTeX
\end{document}
```

but when I run it as follows, it does not work:

```
/tmp/test $ TEXINPUTS=./l3kernel.tds//: pdflatex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021/nixos.org) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(/nix/store/lw99xzbz6hw1mzg1zh9n1wxzpa497s25-texlive-combined-full-2021-final/s
hare/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class

(/nix/store/lw99xzbz6hw1mzg1zh9n1wxzpa497s25-texlive-combined-full-2021-final/s
hare/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(./l3kernel.tds/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty

! LaTeX3 Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.
(LaTeX3)        Loading 'expl3.sty' aborted!
(LaTeX3)
(LaTeX3)        The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format
(LaTeX3)        is dated 2022-02-24, but in your TeX tree the files require
(LaTeX3)        at least 2023-02-22.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.77      \ExplLoaderFileDate{expl3.sty}}
                                         %
?
```

Should this not work? Am I misunderstanding how these `.tds.zip` files can be used?

Comment: expl3 is now part of the format, so you need to rebuild the format files.

Comment: Sorry, but I’m a bit lost what that means. What is “the format”? I am not rebuilding anything, merely trying to use the `.tds.zip` file, as suggested as an easy way to upgrade expl3 in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489649/15107

Comment: you need to run fmtutil-sys --byfmt pdflatex (with your texinputs setting) so that the pdflatex format is rebuilt and uses the new files too.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I fear that this may be quite annoying to get every collaborator (including those on Overleaf) to do properly. Nevertheless, thanks!

Comment: why don't you switch to texlive 2022? it is on overleaf too.

Comment: Would that help? The message says “the files require at least 2023-02-22.”

Comment: depends on which expl3 version/function your package needs. It is imho quite probable that it will work with the version in texlive 2022

Comment: The package in question is `siunitx`, and the latest version seems to ask for expl3 `2022-11-09` … anyways, I can try once I am off the shaky train wifi :-)

Comment: could get difficult. siunitx really wants a newer version to use the new \codepoint_generate:nn function.

Comment: are you _sure_ you want to do this? if you install a pakage-specific expl3, you will need to build a custom latex command for that package, and it will be incompatible with the rest of your tex input tree. It is not impossble, but a lot of work for almost no gain.

Comment: Probably not… but I _would_ like to get a bug-fixed `siunitx` version somehow to not get my results formatted wrongly :-). But I have a work-around (round in python, not in LaTeX), so not pressing.